# Flink's failure recovery process

Tags: apache-flink

I want to know the detailed failure recovery process of flink.In standalone mode, I guess some steps, such as a TaskManager failure, first detect the failure, all tasks stop processing, and then redeploy the tasks. Then download the checkpoint from HDFS, and each operator loads the state. After the loading is completed, the source continues to send data. Am I right? Does anyone know the correct and detailed recovery process?

Answer (score 0):

Flink recovers from failure through checkpoints. Checkpoints can be stored locally, in S3 or HDFS. When restored, all states of different operators will be revived.

For detailed recovery process, it really depends on your backend. If you are using RocksDB.

- your checkpoint can be incremental
- you can use the checkpoint data as a savepoint if you do not need to change the backend. This means you can change the parallelism while reviving from the checkpoint.

Comment: If I use FsStateBackend, it is restored from HDFS. Here are some questions. Are the operators restored in order? When recovering, is flink redeploying the entire execution graph? I found through the UI that some operators changed the running nodes.